# Why occlusion query results are inaccurate when multisampling enabled?

Tags: 3d, directx, direct3d

Recently, I use occlusion query technology in my project and it works fine when not enabling multisampling (msaa). But when I enable multisampling, I found occlusion query results are inaccurate, sometimes it will return < 10 pixels even if I'm sure that the object is obscured.
I guess it is caused by the depth buffer multisampling, but I am not sure. I use D3D9. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but better late than newer, even if it's just for future readers.

It appears that occlusion queries return the number of **samples** that pass the depth test, and therefore you should divide the result by the sample count of your color/depth buffers to get the real result in pixels.

This is the case for all APIs, but seems like only D3D9 wrongly documents those queries as "returning pixels". MSDN docs should probably be updated to be truthful.